# Using Express module in Nodejs to receive a file and a json data

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express for my REST request. I need in the same request to receive a file and a JSON metadata. I am accessing the files from the `req.files` but the problem is that the `req.body` came empty.

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: "./uploads" }));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
});
```

I am trying in the content type multipart/form-data and application/json but no one is solving the problem. Maybe is impossible to receive both?

Comment: How do you make a request?

Comment: using the Rest console in chrome developed by code in chaos

Comment: Can you not pass the object as a parameter? I am doing the same thing, but sending from PhoneGap instead of REST Console, and that's how I am doing it.